# Is there a way to pull a file name based on extension but potentially unknown value?

Tags: sql, select

I've got a database where files are stored and, in one table, their filenames and a sequence number per record number, as well as, in another table, the record number those files are assigned to.  I have an application that is front-end facing to this database, and I want to be able to pull the filenames from that table but ONLY the PDF files.  The problem is that, due to the application limitations (and no, I can't change them; it's a bug with the code that the software designer is working on), it will only allow me to pull one file name per column in the application's results display, instead of just displaying all the file names associated to that record in one column, separated by a comma, etc.

I just want the application to pull filenames if the file is a PDF, however, in order to pull filenames into that application at all, I have to identify a unique quality per record number, which in this case is the sequence number (seqno).  I'm wanting to write a statement that says "pull this filename by sequence number IF the file is a PDF" that doesn't cause empty columns.  So, in other words, if this record has five files attached, and two are PDF, I don't want five columns, three of which are empty, and two of which have data displayed.  I want just the file names delivered into the first two columns.  If the next record has five files attached and three are PDF, then the files should display in the next three columns.

[image]

Original code is below.  This just finds all files attached to a record, pulling file name info from dbo.FILE and record name info from R.FILE_REV and assigns one file name per column by sequence number (R.SEQNO number obviously increases by 1 for each column).  This code works fine; I just want to be able to not have to type it out over and over and have empty columns if it happens that a file with seq_no 2 is not a PDF.

```
SELECT F.FILENAME
FROM dbo.FILE F,
     dbo.FILE_REV R
WHERE F.FILE_NO = R.FILE_NO
  AND R.RECORD_NO = {RECORD_NO}
  AND R.SEQNO = '1'
```

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: A spreadsheet-guru would call that a *"crosstab"* or maybe a *"pivot table,"* and I do know that many SQLs these days have some sort of capability to build those with a query.  Don't know the answer for *your* version, but maybe this will be a "nudge" in the right direction . . .

Answer (score 1):

You can join and do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    r.record_no,
    max(case when r.seqno = 1 then f.filename end) associated_file_1,
    max(case when r.seqno = 2 then f.filename end) associated_file_2,
    max(case when r.seqno = 3 then f.filename end) associated_file_3
from dbo.file_rev r
left join dbo.file f
    on  f.file_no = r.file_no
    and f.filename like '%.pdf'
group by r.record_no
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the sequential number (`seqno`) may not be consecutive, you'll need to produce a sequential number using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function. Then you can pivot the data into the shape you want.

For example:

```
select
  record_no,
  max(case when rn = 1 then f.filename end) as associated_file_1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then f.filename end) as associated_file_2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then f.filename end) as associated_file_3
from (
  select 
    r.record_no,
    f.filename,
    row_number() over(order by r.seqno) as rn
  from dbo.file f
  left join dbo.file_rev r on r.file_no = r.file_no
  where r.record_no = {record_no}
    and f.filename like '%.pdf'
) x
group by record_no
```